# Upgrade DB Loop - WordPress DB Version Conflict

Tags: mysql

So I did an auto update to WP 3.3 and got a screen telling me there was a DB upgrade needed. I hit continue and it said the upgrade was a success. I hit continue again and the same screen popped up telling me the DB needed upgrading... repeat cycle.

Then I changed the DB version in version.php (18226) to match what was in the database under the options table for DB version (19470). This allows me to access the backend, but nothing will update. Can't update any post or pages. It says the page is updated, but it never actually does...

I have read and tried all of these solutions:

[Site stuck in "Database Update Required" loop](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20144/site-stuck-in-database-update-required-loop)

http://blog.nexcess.net/2011/11/15/how-to-fix-the-wordpress-admin-upgrade-loop/

http://www.clickonf5.org/2247/solution-database-upgrade-required/

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by changing the DB credentials in wp-config.php. Apparently, they were wrong...

Answer (score 1):

I've had this issue before. I stumbled on [a really old article from Mark Jaquith](http://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2006/03/28/wordpress-error-you-do-not-have-sufficient-permissions-to-access-this-page/) on forcing an update. The plugin I'm linking to was originally made to update from **1.5.x** to **2.0.x**. I was in a bind so I gave it a shot. I did have recent back-ups for my DB so I wasn't too worried. Luckily [the plugin](http://txfx.net/files/wordpress/force-upgrade.phps) still worked. What version does it does it currently show your using?