# redirected to "welcome to 3.8.5" after automatic upgrade to 4.1.1 now other admin links give 500 error

Tags: upgrade

I ran the automatic upgrade from 3.8.5 to 4.1.1 but had fumbled the backups. Now in the admin area only the `wp-admin/about.php?updated` page works showing me "Welcome to 3.8.5" and inviting me to upgrade again. If I click any other link such as Users or Post I get a white screen and a 500 error in the log. Clicking on the upgrade button seems to work in that it prints up the full upgrade steps it is running including the database upgrade. Yet when it finishes it reloads the page and it still says its is version 3.8.5 and nothing is fixed. Manually upgrading using the [Upgrading_WordPress_Extended](http://codex.wordpress.org/Upgrading_WordPress_Extended) to delete and copy files doesn't fix it. Looking in the logs when I click on Users or Posts I see HTTP 500 errors such as:

```
81.2.110.237 - - [19/Mar/2015:04:32:50 -0400] "GET /wp-admin/users.php HTTP/1.1" 500 - "http://XXX/wp-admin/about.php?updated" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.89 Safari/537.36"
```

The public front of the site is working fine its just the admin area which is trashed. Given that I have run the "extended manual upgrade" without that clearing the issue what can I do to force through the upgrade and remove the broken redirect to `about.php?updated`.

Some more information:

1. The site is running on a redhat openshift php-53 cartridge.
2. Running `md5sum *` run in wp-admin folder of the site then comparing the output with same run in the folder unzipped from wordpress-4.1.1.zip shows that it is 4.11 on the site. Ditto for wp-includes folder. Going to `/wp-admin/upgrade.php` shows `Your WordPress database is already up-to-date!` so it seems my database is up to date.
3. Guessing it was silent failure to overwrite files due to permissions I did `chown -R me:mygroup *` to see if there were any files owned by some system account which gave no errors then `chmod -R o+w *` to give world write. Then I reran the automatic upgrade on the page the admin area is stuck on. Once again it ran to completion without errors but nothing got fixed. So I have run `chmod -R o-w *` to revert world write.

Then things get really weird. I backup the db and site folders on the linux host and restore them in a local MAMP install on my mac. When I got to login to the local copy it says `Database Upgrade Required` so I run that, it all works, and I can use the site locally all fine. So now I think all I have to do is restore the upgraded local database back into the server then I will be all good. So I restore the database, hit the wp-admin, and get `Database Upgrade Required`. Okay maybe the restore didn't work but this looks like progress. I click `Upgrade WordPress Database` and it hangs showing no put stopped at the url `wp-admin/upgrade.php?step=1&backto=%2Fwp-admin%2F`. I look at the server database and it has the same rest password hash I set locally so I actually think I had installed the copy of the working local database (upgraded) into the server. Dumping the linux database and comparing it to the last backup the primary key of the `comments` table has changed so it would appear that the database has now had some upgrade code run against it.

Digging around in the backups I see that the `options` table has a load of site configuration in it. The latest backup shows:

```
(56,'db_version','30133','yes') 
(164,'db_upgraded','','yes')
```

and the `wp-includes/version.php` shows:

```
$wp_version = '4.1.1';
$wp_db_version = 30133;
```

So the system thinks it is update as the db_version is correct.

Comment: This post is also useful http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20144/site-stuck-in-database-update-required-loop?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Eventually after confirming that the database had been updated I rebooted the server I tried moving the file `wp-admin/upgrade.php` to be `wp-admin/411.upgrade.php`. This got the site out of its death spiral.

Given that I had manually updated all the files using [Upgrading_WordPress_Extended](http://codex.wordpress.org/Upgrading_WordPress_Extended) and had also managed to get the database upgrade installer to run as shown by the `db_version` being 30133 entry in the `_options` table if you run into the same problem trying moving that script out of the way.