# wordpress 'database update required' loop after update

Tags: database

I tried to update my WordPress version but it didn't work.
If I log in I get the message

> Database Update Required. WordPress has been updated! Before we send you on your way, we have to update your database to the newest version. The update process may take a while, so please be patient.

After clicking Update now I get the Message

> Update complete. Your WordPress database has been successfully updated.

But after clicking on OK I get the first message again.

After reading a couple of threads I tried this:

- clearing browser cache and cookies
- checking PHP Version
- renaming/deactivating plugin-folder
- renaming/deactivating WordPress installation folder
- restoring WordPress and Database from my backups
- attempt a database repair with `define('WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true);` [Site stuck in "Database Update Required" loop](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20144/site-stuck-in-database-update-required-loop)
- I don't have a `db_upgraded`field in my /wp-include/options.php so i couldn't set it to `0` [Site stuck in "Database Update Required" loop](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20144/site-stuck-in-database-update-required-loop)
- I can't find the `db_version` value under `wp_options` in my database. So I can't check it like here [Wordpress 3.9 Database Update Infinite Loop](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/141731/wordpress-3-9-database-update-infinite-loop)

but nothing worked. I still can't get to the backend.

Could anyone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling across this now, I might have the solution.
If you've tried the above steps provided by OP, instead of matching the database functions lower the `db_version` value in the `wp_options` by 1. In case your `$wp_db_version` in your `version.php` is 45805 (as was the case for me), try setting your `db_version` value in the `wp_options` table to 45804.

Doing so will set your WordPress to prompt you to update the database once again when you visit the /wp-login or /wp-admin screen. This, again in my case, solved the problem.